# Bootstrap nav justified odd responsive issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

The nav starts out great once you lower the bowser width the nav becomes stacked, this is great. Once you open the window back up the nav items are in two rows. Here's a pic.

[image]

This is how it starts out:

[image]

http://reggi.myshopify.com/pages/about#

Comment: filed issue in github https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is a known bug with Bootstrap.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9774)

This has been fixed in Chrome Since 2013, but is still an [open bug in WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=138167) and occurs in Safari.

> Safari exhibits a bug in which resizing your browser horizontally causes rendering errors in the justified nav that are cleared upon refreshing. This bug is also shown in the justified nav example.
>   — [cvrebert](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/4cbc8d49b10f707029019aaa5eba50e56390a3c5)

I recommend to not use `.nav-justified` or be ok with it not working properly in Safari.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, I found that forcing a redraw of the `.nav-justified` element in question helps WebKit understand. Obviously, how you chose to do this is up to you—I opted for the `fadeIn()`, 'cause when life hands you lemons...

```
$(window).bind('resize', function(){
    var w = $(this).width(),
        threshold = 768;

        if(w < threshold){
            $('.nav-justified').hide().fadeIn();
        }
});
```

Comment: thanks for this!  Seems like the issue happens when resizing from *.width() <=768px back to >768px.  One can choose, as I did, to apply this band aid only when this situation occurs.

Comment: Also, you can use parameters of *.fadeIn(speed, easing, callback) to further improve the solution, For example, use *.fadeIn(0) to reduce fade in time to 0 milliseconds, so the redraw effect is instant.  The default value is 400ms.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers seem to be lacking. The JS solution causes a lot of flicker, and the CSS solution doesn't seem to keep the integrity of the designed tabs. Here's what I came up with.

If you're not using less with your bootstrap styles just replace @screen-sm with 768px

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm) {
    .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 32.9999%
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `display: table-cell;` instruction in the `.nav-justified` class.

Let's take a look at the `bootstrap.css` file, I believed that you are using `Bootstrap version 3.0`, at line 4109.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }
```

You must change it to :

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
      .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 100px;
      }

}
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: I'd prefer to not edit the bootstrap source. Is there a way to overwrite the bootstrap media query?

Comment: Of course yes, you just need to create a class in your CSS file and add the code above into it. After that, you specify your new class in the li tag.

Comment: Note that if you don't want to add it in each li tag, you can add it to ul tag and use .newClass > li, as Bootstrap did, or etc ways.

Comment: @ThomasReggi - Did this (or something else) sort out this issue for you? The above is *not* working for me, sadly.

Comment: @cuzzi Nope, didn't work either. I ended up ditching `.nav-justified`.

Comment: @ThomasReggi - Yeah, I nearly did too, then I ended up finding a fix. See my answer above.